# randint() issue with Python number guessing game

Tags: python, random

The following is a snippet of code that is supposed to make a higher lower game. It is supposed to get a random number between two variables. But it doesn't go in between the 2 variables. Just try it and you will see.

```
from random import randint
high = 1000
low = 1
guess_num = 5
def me_guess(guess_num,high,low):
  print " "
  guess_num = randint(low,high)
  guess_num = str(guess_num)
  fact = raw_input(guess_num + " (higher or lower or yes) ")
  if fact == "higher":
    guess_num = low
    me_guess(guess_num,high,low)
  elif fact == "lower":
    guess_num = high
    me_guess(guess_num,high,low)
  elif fact == "yes":
    print "Yay! I got it."
    me_finish(guess_num)
  else:
    print "Error. Guessing again."
    me_guess(guess_num,high,low)
  me_guess(guess_num,high,low)
```

Comment: Do you think "Python error (please help)" is a good title for your question?

Comment: What else should I name it?

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @djtravz: if the please-help begging is removed from the original title, that would leave "Python error". OK, you're using Python and you're getting an error, but that probably still describes maybe a hundred thousand questions on the site. Try to make them a bit more specific, without writing an essay. Keep titles chat-free. Remember they are the first thing people see when you ask a tech question, and so it's worth making a good impression. Good titles help future readers (and searchers) too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the "low" not "guess_num" ,the same for "max" in the if else statments...

> `guess_num = low` should be `low = guess_num`

also don't str() guess_num

```
from random import randint
high = 1000
low = 1
guess_num = 5
def me_guess(guess_num,high,low):
  print " "
  guess_num = randint(low,high)

  fact = raw_input(str(guess_num) + " (higher or lower or yes) ")
  if fact == "higher":
    low = guess_num
    me_guess(guess_num,high,low)
  elif fact == "lower":
    high = guess_num
    me_guess(guess_num,high,low)
  elif fact == "yes":
    print "Yay! I got it."
    me_finish(guess_num)
  else:
    print "Error. Guessing again."
    me_guess(guess_num,high,low)

me_guess(guess_num,high,low)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That was just a silly mistake. :)